# Heat Equation textbook question

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I've been working through my textbooks in preparation for my exams and found this problem. I'm not really sure the best way to solve this as normally the initial conditions are much more detailed. Any help on how to get started would be greatly appreciated.

[image: pg152 textbook exercise]

Honestly I'm really struggling to make headway on this example.